# Recognizing relationship/pattern

Tags: pattern-recognition

I have some data that I know are related but I can't seem to find the exact relationship. Was hoping someone could help find it. Left column data is related to the right column.

```
1160786507      E02K
1432646245      Udre
1211119187      H06S
1214345830      HARF
1211117653      H00U
1429221446      U00F
1430466865      UC11
```

Comment: Is that **all** the data you have?

Comment: Providing context could help... where does it come from?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like each pair is a different representation of the same thing.  The binary representation of `1160786507` is `01000101001100000011001001001011`.  Taken 8 bits at a time, that gives:

- `01000101`
- `00110000`
- `00110010`
- `01001011`

In decimal that looks more like this:

- 69
- 48
- 50
- 75

According to this [ASCII Table](http://www.asciitable.com/), those digits respectively represent the characters `E`, `0`, `2`, and `K`.

So essentially the left column is what you would get if you saved the right column as ASCII but then interpreted it as a 32-bit integer instead of a string of characters.

**Update**: For those wondering how I saw this, I noticed that the numbers on the left all were exactly 10 digits long and began with a 1.  Spend enough time programming and you come to know off the top of your head that the maximum value of a signed 32-bit integer is roughly 2.1 billion, so it seems that might be the reason why all those 10-digit numbers began with 1.  Also I noticed that all the character strings on the right had exactly 4 characters, and since characters are often encoded using 8 bits, that means they also can be represented using 32 bits.  From there I just had to check if one of the popular encoding schemes worked out, and indeed ASCII did the trick.

The moral is that humans are surprisingly good (oftentimes too good) at pattern recognition.

Comment: holy smokes!  this is so clever it almost seems that the question was a plant :-)

Comment: Hmmm. The strange part is that the right column reads `E02K` and not `K20E`. The latter is how the integer in the left-hand column would be stored in memory on probably 99+% of modern personal computers. ([Endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness))